# How to efficiently fill a 2D std::array with enum

Tags: c++, arrays, enums, c++14, stdarray

I am trying to find an efficient and proper way to fill a 2D `std::array` matrix with an `enum` value.  I am doing this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<class T, size_t ROW, size_t COL>
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<T, COL>, ROW>;

enum class State { FREE = 0, BUSY, BLOCKED, RESERVED };

int main() {
  const int mapX = 4;
  const int mapY = 9;

  // create a 5x10 2D array
  Matrix<State, mapY, mapX> MapMatrix;

  // fill array with State::RESERVED value
  for (int y = 0; y <= mapY; y++) MapMatrix[y].fill(State::RESERVED);

  std::cout << "MapMatrix contains:\n";

  for (int y = 0; y <= mapY; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x <= mapX; ++x) {
      std::cout << static_cast<int>(MapMatrix[x][y]) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Is the *for loop* I am doing the best way to fill the matrix with the `enum` value?  Is there a way to fill the matrix during the declaration of `Matrix<State, mapY, mapX> MapMatrix` (like a constructor)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a loop based initialization is a good solution.

But, just for fun, I propose you another solution `std::index_sequence` and  template pack expansion based.

A working example (with index corrected)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

template <typename T, std::size_t ROW, std::size_t COL>
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<T, COL>, ROW>;

enum class State { FREE = 0, BUSY, BLOCKED, RESERVED };

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Rs, std::size_t ... Cl>
Matrix<T, sizeof...(Rs), sizeof...(Cl)> initMat
   (T                          const & tVal,
    std::index_sequence<Rs...> const &,
    std::index_sequence<Cl...> const &)
 {
   auto col = std::array<T, sizeof...(Cl)>{ { ((void)Cl, tVal)... } };

   return Matrix<T, sizeof...(Rs), sizeof...(Cl)>
    { { ((void)Rs, col)... } };
 }

int main()
 {
   constexpr std::size_t mapX =  5U;
   constexpr std::size_t mapY = 10U;

   // create a 5x10 2D array
   auto MapMatrix = initMat(State::RESERVED,
                            std::make_index_sequence<mapX>(),
                            std::make_index_sequence<mapY>());

   std::cout << "MapMatrix contains:\n";

   for ( auto y = 0U ; y < mapY ; ++y )
    {
      for ( auto x = 0U ; x < mapX ; ++x )
         std::cout << static_cast<int>(MapMatrix[x][y]) << " ";

      std::cout << std::endl;
    }

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I really like your solution, great example!  It also makes the code less confusing in regards to start index.  When I get back tonight, I will do _chrono::duration_ test on a large map initialisation and compare with the range-for loop fill.  Thanks!

Comment: If I do a 500x100 array, your method takes 0.182116 ms on my computer to fill the array, whereas the range-for loop takes 0.388968 ms, that's a great performance boost!  It would have been easier to benchmark if I could get into very large numbers (10000x10000) but I get SEGFAULTS at that point...  Thanks again!

Comment: @Simog - take in count that `std::array` put data in stack; so, for large numbers, you should use `std::vector` (or others heap based containers) or `std::array` through smart pointers

Comment: yeah I assumed it was the stack size when I googled the issue.  I don't really need it that big for the application anyway, just wanted some better numbers to compare. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can't fill it on initialization unless you are filling it with zeros, or you specify every element explicitly. If you rearranged your enum so that `RESERVED` is zero, then you could initialize it like this:

```
Matrix<State, mapY, mapX> MapMatrix = {};
```

If you can't do that, then yes, a for loop is probably the best option. Keep it simple. But you have a few problems. First, your comment says that you are creating a 5x10 array, but you are not. You are creating a 4x9 array. If you want to create a 5x10 array, then you need to pass 5 and 10 as your template parameters. I think you're probably getting confused by the fact that the last element of an array of size N is N - 1. This off-by-one issue is only relevant to accessing elements of an array, not in specifying the size of an array.

Second, you are iterating past the end of your array, because your loop condition is `y <= mapY`, rather than `y < mapY`. But it would be better if you just used a range-for loop.

```
for (auto& arr : MapMatrix)
    arr.fill(State::RESERVED);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.  Yes I was counting 5x10 by including the "start at 0" index.  Also, just tested your range-for loop, works perfectly.  I can't change the value of RESERVED, but it isn't so much of a big deal to use a range-for loop.  I though maybe I was overthinking this.